# start docker container after traefik is up an running

Tags: docker, traefik

I have traefik in one docker file and several other container using traefik in other docker files for the sake of organization.
When my host launches, sometimes one of the client containers seems to start before traefik is up and running and therefore doesn't register correctly. When restarting the container, everything works. The timing seems to be kind of random, as most times it works fine in the correct order.

How can I implement a check in my client docker container, so that it only starts when traefik is up and running? Health check with ping is already working with traefik.

Comment: "How can I implement a check in my client docker container..." You can't: any check you implement *in your container* by definition would mean that your container has already started, so you would still have the same problem. I am surprised that you are seeing this ordering issue; Traefik should work correctly with containers that have already started. Are you using a docker restart policy to start things when the system boots, or some other mechanism?

Comment: yes, I use restart: always

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem: if I start up a labelled container and then afterwards start up traefik, it successfully discovers the existing container. Try enabling debug logging in traefik (`--log.level=DEBUG`) and then examine the traefik logs after startup. Look in particular for the `Configuration received:` lines, as well as for the `Creating load-balancer` lines.